# The agent operating system doesn't support Node20. Using Node16 instead

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops

I am getting this warning in my **`azure release pipelines`** and what is the solution for this warning.

it will impact anything on my release pipeline.

```
##[warning]The agent operating system doesn't support Node20. Using Node16 instead. Please upgrade the operating system of the agent to remain compatible with future updates of tasks: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions
```

I tried searching on google and stackoverflow but not get any proper solution.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/dnceng/issues/1743 > Refer this Github issue Also use Node Installer to install the appropriate node package- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817127/azure-devops-vsts-build-agent-using-different-version-of-node

Comment: Also, Its just a warning

Comment: @brucewayne, may i know if there's any update? Does the answer below work for you? Feel free to ask if you still have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning, That some Ubuntu Linux Agents and in your mentioned link Ubuntu Bionic ^18.04 does not support Node 18x, Node 20x and Node 21. Also, some Azure Devops agent has Node 16.0.0 installed on them by default, This warning suggests that it will use the existing node from the agent. But you can manually install the NodeJs version of your choice by using the Build and Release task like below:-

Refer this [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dnceng/issues/1743) on the same error.

***Build yaml pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSource: 'spec'
    versionSpec: '20.0.0'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'  # Adjust this path based on your project structure
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
  displayName: 'Archive Files'

- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
  artifact: drop
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
```

I am using **`ubuntu-latest`** agent.

[image]

Output:-

[image]

***In Release pipeline:-***

[image]

*Node Install task:-*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Siddesh
My case "The agent operating system doesn't support Node20" still i can use node20.js version or different version. my agent is taking node16